# Issue creating TPU node "Unknown Error" (Google Cloud Platform)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, tpu

Is anyone able to create a TPU node today? I had no issues prior to today but have been getting an "Unknown error" message all day when trying to create a TPU node.

I checked my quotas and no issue there so I don't understand why suddenly I cannot create a TPU node. Is it just down or is it me? I put in a request for assistance but I am unable to get in contact with anyone.

Comment: Did you find any relevant logs for the TPU resource?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the logs under logs explorer, also if the project is part of vpc sc perimeter, check the ipv6 settings on your local machine, should be set to link local.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could also try creating Cloud TPU VM using `gcloud` command from the command line following the instructions provided in [gcloud compute instances create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create). If you hit an error, you could see error messages on the command line.